# Restore data from a cricket graph file in macintosh 1984

Tags: macos

I have a cricket graph file that is old, it's kinda like excel of our days, I want to restore this data, I have downloaded a macintosh emulator, called macintosh.js it's based on an electron app, anyway I have installed this software called cricket graph, but the problem is that the program doesn't recognize this file, and there is no way to change the file `kind` in this system or to make this app as a default program for this file.

Any help please?

*good to mention that both Science Data and Business Data files opened correctly, they are provided by default with this program.

[image: screenshot]